# C# My First Singleton Attempt Apparently Not Quite Right

Tags: c#, singleton

In my website there are dozens of calls made to a sql database and each time it passes along the ID of the user requesting data. I'm attempting to set up a singleton class that will only need to make one call to the database to grab the person's ID along with other user attributes that only need to be grabbed once.

I thought I had everything set up properly and it seemed to be working so I moved the code change into production and have gotten calls from several users saying when they log in, they are all being identified as me. This is based on the welcome message at the top of my home page that says "Welcome ", and everybody's userName is showing as me.

My singleton is below. After getting the call I started debugging, what I have found is that the formValues() method where I thought the values are being set is never getting called.  The only thing that does get called is the public Instance method. I'm guessing that's obvious to everybody that knows what they are doing :).

I don't think this is relevant, but the instance of the variables is being called in my code like: formValues.Instance.firstName.

So how close am I? Is this thing salvageable?

```
public sealed class formValues : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    static readonly formValues instance = new formValues();

    public string userName;
    public string firstName;
    public string personID;
    public string secBlur;
    public int admin;
    public int fafsa;
    public int staff;

    static formValues()
    {

    }

    formValues()
    {
        //This retrieves the person logged into windows/active directory
        FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
        userName = id.Name;

        // Grab this user's firstname, personID, and Admin status
        string mySQL = "exec get_userData @userName";
        string cf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DistrictAssessmentDWConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cf);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(mySQL, connection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);

        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                personID = dr["personID"].ToString();
                firstName = dr["firstName"].ToString();
                admin = Convert.ToInt32(dr["admin"]);
                secBlur = dr["secBlur"].ToString();
                fafsa = Convert.ToInt32(dr["FAFSA"]);
                staff = Convert.ToInt32(dr["staffSec"]);
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    public static formValues Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the field is static there isn't a way to garauntee when the singleton will first be constructed. It's unlikely that you'll have the desired HttpContext at the time of construction, and it won't be constructed for each individual user. Singleton seems like the wrong approach to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathon Chase, I'm open to suggestions...do you have recommendations on a better approach?

Comment: You could adjust it by removing the `instance` field and property, and instead add a factory method named `Create` that calls your constructor. This would let you create and populate the object on demand.

Comment: Use @JonSkeet's `Lazy<T>` singleton pattern at: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that these properties (fields, actually) are in a singleton:

```
public string userName;
public string firstName;
public string personID;
public string secBlur;
public int admin;
public int fafsa;
public int staff;
```

...along with the fact that they get populated in the constructor. That means the first time you create the class, it gets populated. If you re-use that same class instance as a singleton, the constructor will never get called again, which means that the values populated will be set once and remain forever.

In other words, your user data is a singleton. Unless you will only have one user ever, that's not good.

First, I would separate the class that retrieves the data from the class that contains the data.

The data might look like this:

```
public class UserData
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // ..etc...
}
```

That model contains the data. It does not contain the code to populate the data.

Then, create a class that retrieves the data. It shouldn't retrieve the data in the constructor. The constructor is for creating the class. It's not where we would put the stuff that the class actually does.

That class might have a method like this:

```
public UserData GetUserData()
```

...which would create an instance of `UserData` and return it.

---

For what it's worth, for most scenarios we don't need to create a singleton.

Suppose you have this class:

```
public class SqlUserDataProvider
{
    UserData GetUserData()
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

If the constructor doesn't do anything "heavy" like read data or files, you could just create a new instance each time you need one. It's less efficient than using a single instance, but the difference is usually so minutely trivial that it's not worth considering.

Or, you can create a single instance and re-use it. In that case you're using it as a singleton, but technically it isn't one. A singleton is class written so that it is only possible to create a single instance of it. Most of the time there's just no reason to do that. It's extra lines of code to strictly enforce a restriction on how we use the class. It can potentially make code less maintainable and harder to debug. So it's extra work for either no benefit or negative benefit.

Comment: Since you've tried creating a singleton and you've mentioned caching, it sounds like what you want is to call this once for each web request and then avoid calling it over and over again during that same request. Is that accurate? If so, there are ways to do that. I didn't go into that because it's not what the question is about. Is this a Web Service, like with .asmx files?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to do a cache. For http requests you need to check if value is already in cache, if it is not - read from the database, otherwise use cache. 
You can start with built-in [Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.caching.cache?view=netframework-4.7.2)

As for singletons, simplest solution is to implement them using Lazy. Here is [good article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lazy)

Comment: I tried using cache yesterday, and it was randomly grabbing the IDs of users logged into the website -- everytime I hit refresh it would welcome me as a different person :(. Obviously, there is something I"m doing at the core that seems to be correct.  @Jonathan Chase said something that's making me wonder -- I thought HttpContext would grab the name of the person authenticated from the "calling" computer...do I need to give myself a refresher course on how the http commands work?

Answer (score 0):

The instance object is created just once on an application lifetime.
So your private constructor formValues(), where you get the FormsIdentity, is actually executed just once after application starts up first time ever.

After that , for all incoming requests, the already populated instance is given out.
That's why you see the same username, for any further requests.

Since the requirement is per-user basis, and not something global across application, "singleton" probably wont help. Thanks.